# Xamarin Shell hierarchy with child page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I have specified a trival page structure in a Xamarin Shell v5 app. I have a flyout with flyout items in the following structure:

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
<ShellContent>
    <local:MainPage...
</ShellContent>
<ShellContent>
    <local:Page1...
</ShellContent>
<ShellContent>
    <local:Page2...
</ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

When I start the app the MainPage is displayed as default. So far so good.

The flyout displays the three pages. Also good.

When I tap on the Page2 flyout, *that* page is displayed. But a navigation stack isn't created, meaning it also displays the hamburger menu (instead of the back button where the hamburger icon is).

I would like to have Page2 be a "child page" (navigation-wise) so that when a user taps the Page2 flyout a back button is displayed at the top so the user can go back to the Homepage.

I've been reading the documentation backwards and forwards, and can't figure out how to do this in the visual shell hierarchy.
I assume it has to do with routes, but I'm not sure how to specify routes so Page2 becomes a 'sub-page' (or whatever the word is).

Does anyone know how to do this? This applies to both iOS and Android.

I would prefer not to have the tabs displayed at the bottom of the screen as I've seen in many examples. Just a neat, clean flyout menut.

Comment: I know that I can use menu items instead, and in each menu item's callback I can call ```Shell.Current.GoToAsync(.....)``` which will, with the correct route, push pages onto a navigation stack. And I might just have to do that, but I'm curious whether this can be done with flyoutitems alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using MenuItems instead of FlyoutItems. In the callback for each MenuItem I call `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("");` which opens the page as a *child*, i.e. back navigation can be performed.
And since menu items can be styled (just like flyout items), it looks nice on the device. It's a workaround, but one I'm happy with.

Answer (score 2):

If the pages are still in the Shell hierachical structure(the page2 in the `FlyoutItem`), the hamburger icon would show always.

You could use the code below to register the pages that do not exist in the Shell visual hierachy. And then when you navigate to these pages, you could use the back button to go back.

```
 Routing.RegisterRoute("page2", typeof(Pages));
```

Navigate:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("page2");
```

Comment: Yes, calling GoToAsync() creates a navigation stack. The question is how I perform nesting of pages in the Shell Visual Hierarchy.

Comment: What does the nesting of pages mean? Do you mean nest a page in the pages of Shell Visual Hierarchy without any navigations?

Comment: Display: linear, i.e. one pag after another in a vertical list. In xaml (visual hiearchy): don't care. Navigation when tapping: page 2 is _added_ to the nav stack. If I call Shell.Current.GoToAsync it is _added_ to the nav stack. If I tap on it a new nav stack is created. I would like (if possible) to declare somehow in the shell visual hierarchy that the page should be _added_ to the nav stack when I tap on it. I hope that makes sense. Like (pseudo xaml) <FlyoutItem IsChildPage="true">...

Comment: It is the special features of Shell template to use routes to navigate to any page in the application. Why do you want to avoid this? How about use the other templates?

Comment: I don't want to avoid it :-) I swapped the FlyoutItems and I'm now using MenuItems instead. In their respective callback I call Shell.Current.GoToAsync("<pagename>") and in the end it _looks_ like FlyoutItems, but _behaves_ like I want (open a 'child' page). When the child page is opened, I can navigate back by hitting the back arrow button. Problem solved, albeit via a workaround of using menu items instead of flyout items.